# Javascript array push is not giving desired result

Tags: javascript

The problem I am having is when im pushing or unshifting items into array they are being automatically grouped, very strange:im guessing my loops are not well put together, more or less im experimenting.any help is appreciated.

```
   var i;
   var anObject:/*is created dynamically in a loop for instance I load random images
   and push into  ' myArray'. My myaArray should
   look like this:["image1,image3,image2,image3,image2] but instead 
   im getting:["image1,image3,image3,image2,image2] there grouping up for some reason,
   But i dont   want them too*/


  var BookH = []; 

  function create(){ 
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
   var object;
    var tempObject;
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load( 'mod/'+mysqlVars[i].Format+'.obj','mod/bookH.mtl') ;
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
           object = event.content;
           for(k in object.children){
               object.children[k].castShadow = true;
               object.children[k].receiveShadow = false;

           } 

          tempObject = object.clone();
          BookH.push(tempObject);
          console.log('mod/'+mysqlVars[9].Format);
          if(BookH.length == 10){
               populate();
           }
         });
    }

    /////////counter loop///
}
```

Comment: The code you posted won't do what your comments suggest. Please post an example that does exhibit the problem: there might be something in the way you're creating your objects that causes the difficulty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/54RUY/ it just fine.

Comment: i just updated to my source

Comment: it seems to be a looping problem

Comment: rq : add the event listener *before* calling load.

Comment: i tried but then theres nothing to load, event listener is waiting on the load

Comment: add both load an error listener before calling to load, then.

Comment: no luck, the problem im finding is inside the load function i need it to break out and continue illaterating

Comment: Why do you think the answer must be `[image1,image3,image2,image3,image2]`? I see nothing in the documentation that says that `load` events will fire in any particular order.Also, you are sharing the `object` variable among all the callbacks, which is dangerous.

Comment: the reason is im using adata base to extract info, it returns in java in an array of myVar[i].label when i trace this variable its in an order which is random so need to use that.i understand the issues with sharing vars and what have you but im really just trying to get the basic overhaul to work ...